# Gnome-System-Monitor has no GTK Window Decoration

Tags: gtk, gnome-classic, window-decoration

Really simple problem that I can't seem to figure out. The window decorator works for everything else, but whenever I open the system monitor, it opens in full screen with no border. I'm using Gnome Classic as my DE if that matters at all. Anyone know a fix or workaround to this?

EDIT:
Seems to only happen when it's not started as root.

Comment: Have you tried to open another program as root?

Comment: What do you mean? 
So far, when started as a normal user, gnome-system-monitor starts with no title bar or border. When started as root, it has a title bar and border.

Comment: Sorry, I misread

Comment: Does it happen with any theme?