# How do I make System monitor use the same theme as Ubuntu 22.10 Cinnamon 5.4.12

Tags: themes, cinnamon, system-monitor, 22.10

**Ubuntu 22.10 with Cinnamon desktop 5.4.12** not showing **System Monitor 42.0** with same theme:

[image: sysmon-theme]

Ubuntu release updated yesterday 3th november 2022 from 22.04 using lightdm and Cinnamon to Kinetic.

I didn't found any settings to allow to change it:

### [image: processes-settings]

### [image: ressources-settings]

### [image: filesys-settings]

**How can I make it use the same theme?**

I found the same question [here, on github](https://github.com/ubuntu/gnome-shell-communitheme/issues/87), but the problem came from the snap version.

I installed it with `apt install gnome-system-monitor`:
[image: apt-install-gnome-system-monitor]

My current theme settings:
[image: theme-settings]

I found the same issue on [Github](https://github.com/dracula/gtk/issues/127) with another theme. It seems it's gnome-system-monitor that does it wrong with GTK4.
Here another article: https://www.phoronix.com/news/GNOME-HIG-2021-Design describing they are bussy with the implementation of it since 2021.

**Is there no workarround solution since ?**

I made other tests, and it seems gnome themes only are provided with GTK2 support. Am I right?

```
root@lubuton:/home/wingarmac# apt-cache search gnome-theme
gnome-themes-extra - Adwaita GTK+ 2 theme — engine
gnome-themes-extra-data - Adwaita GTK+ 2 theme — common files
gnome-theme-gilouche - openSUSE Gilouche Theme
gnome-themes-standard - Adwaita GTK+ 2 theme — engine - transitional package
gnome-themes-ubuntu - Ubuntu community themes
```

So I can presume it's because gnome-system-monitor isn't GTK4 compatible?

**If so, can I make it use the dark GTK2 theme instead eventually ?**

I also tested the installation of the [snap version](https://snapcraft.io/gnome-system-monitor):

```
root@lubuton:/home/wingarmac# snap install gnome-system-monitor
gnome-system-monitor 42.0 from Canonical✓ installed
```

With same results for both described as follow in the Cinnamon menu:

*(I do not know which one is snaps so I tried both)*

[image: cinnamon-sysmon-search]

These tests where all made on my personal computer till now.
So I've another computer for test, where I did install Ubuntu server 22.10.

After the installation of it:

```
sudo su
apt update && apt upgrade
apt install ubuntu-desktop --no-install-recommends
apt install cinnamon
apt install ubuntu-mate-icon-themes
apt install nvidia-driver*
reboot
```

After logon I've configured my desktop like on my personal computer with the Adwaita dark theme and Yaru red icons.
gnome-system-monitor shows up in dark.

**Other sites visited** *(information - sources - similar issues)*:

- [How to set dark/light mode from the GNOME session in Ubuntu 22.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1405961/how-to-set-dark-light-mode-from-the-gnome-session-in-ubuntu-22-04)
- https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/gnome-session.1.html
- https://www.phoronix.com/news/GNOME-HIG-2021-Design
- [Gnome-System-Monitor has no GTK Window Decoration](https://askubuntu.com/questions/246916/gnome-system-monitor-has-no-gtk-window-decoration)
- https://github.com/dracula/gtk/issues/127
- https://www.reddit.com/r/gnome/comments/tbqydi/gnome_42_dark_mode_not_applied_to_every_window/
- https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/Initiatives/-/wikis/Dark-Style-Preference#other
- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-install-adwaita-icon-theme-on-ubuntu/
- https://github.com/ubuntu/gnome-shell-communitheme/issues/87
- https://snapcraft.io/gnome-system-monitor
- https://github.com/ubuntu/yaru/issues/296

Comment: It seems that you are not using the default Yaru theme. If the theme you are using supports GTK4, then this problem will not appear. You can either use a GTK theme that supports GTK4, e.g. Yaru/Arc, or ask the maintainer of your current theme to add support for GTK4.

Comment: Currently I'm using Adwaita-dark for the applications. @ArchismanPanigrahi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some tests I found a solution.

I first took a look to the Cinnamon System Settings in de menu.

It was wrote as comment "Control Center".

Since gnome-system-monitor is from gnome I search for the /bin/gnome-control-center on my current install. I found it and tried to open it:

[image: /bin/gnome-control-center]

From there I could set the dark appearance:

[image: gnome-control-center-apearance]

After that the gnome-system-monitor was also with a dark theme:

[image: sysmon-dark-theme]

I installed the apt version instead of the snap version of gnome-system monitor, since the icon in the taskbar is the last version of it [image: gnome-sysmon-icon], what wasn't the case of the snap version.

Comment: Since the  gnome-system-monitor is gnome software, all gnome-based control panel versions are able to change it's theme. Cinnamon-settings are using another theme interface it seems.

Comment: In the last installations I made, I got the black theme on all gnome pannels immediatly. The order of the packets installed and their version seem to me the only difference. I do not know yet what exactly.